# How to make fontawsome icon spin in a button that is disabled

Tags: css, font-awesome

i have a form with a submit button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success dis-form-button">
  <i class="spinner fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    Sign-in
</button>
```

the spinner icon is hidden on page load.
when i submit the form i catch the onSubmit event and disable the button & show the spinner icon, but the spinner does not spin when the button is disabled?
any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide CSS for your button and spinner icon?

Comment: .disable-after-first-click:disabled {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .spinner {
            display: none;
        }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think your issue lies with the disabled property on the button. This answer is more of a non-answer, but here's a snippet that shows the functionality you described working just fine.

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.dis-form-button').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```css
.dis-form-button .spinner {
  display: none;
}

.dis-form-button:disabled .spinner {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success dis-form-button">
  <i class="spinner fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    Sign-in
</button>
</form>
```

Comment: it works now :/, i changed the .spinner show from jQuery with to css like you suggested and it's working :D, appreciate your contribution..